# Regex pattern to replace the last occurence of a pattern in string

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace only the last occurrence of the pattern `{id}` or `{objId}` or `{anything else}` that appears after the last occurrence of `/` with `xyz` in Java.

Input:

```
/test/data/{id}/moreData/{id}
/test/data/{id}/moreData/{objId}
/test/data/{id}/moreData/{anything else}
```

Expected output:

```
/test/data/{id}/moreData/xyz
/test/data/{id}/moreData/xyz
/test/data/{id}/moreData/xyz
```

Please suggest a regex for this.

Comment: If it's `java` why are you using the `javascript` tag? And what have you tried so far, is there some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clarified in comments, you seem to be looking to replace the last placeholder that appears after a slash `/`. For this you can use following regex,

```
[^/]+$
```

Here, `[^/]` is a negated character class which captures any character except a slash `/` and `+` means one or more characters and `$` means end of string which will ensure this will match any text that appears in end of string not containing `/`. So just match using it and replace with `xyz` or any string of your choice.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4qoHkv/1)**

Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("/test/data/{id}/moreData/{id}","/test/data/{id}/moreData/{objId}","/test/data/{id}/moreData/{anything else}");
list.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " --> " + x.replaceAll("[^/]+$", "xyz")));
```

Prints,

```
/test/data/{id}/moreData/{id} --> /test/data/{id}/moreData/xyz
/test/data/{id}/moreData/{objId} --> /test/data/{id}/moreData/xyz
/test/data/{id}/moreData/{anything else} --> /test/data/{id}/moreData/xyz
```

Comment: Thanks Pushpesh for your inputs. I will try this. 
A small change in my question, that it's not only ID, it can be any identifier within the curly braces. Only the last pattern should be replaced.

Input : /data/{objId}/moreData/{ID}/subData/{subId}

Output : /data/{objId}/moreData/{ID}/subData/xyz

Comment: @Pushpesh - My point is, i won't be knowing the URI pattern, it's depends on some external implementation. Since it's a resourceURI, the assumption is the target resourceID will always be on the end of the string.

So, this can be either {id}, {objId} or {something_else} . I need to replace this.

Also, will it help if we use $ to try specify that i need to replace only the {*} at the end of string

Comment: @MohanS: Ok, I think now your question has become precise and if I am correct, you want to match the last string after `/` and replace that with some string. In this case I'll suggest another regex `[^\/]+$` which will be any text other than `/` just before end of string. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/F4Av5Y/4) and let me know if this works better.

Comment: This helps, Thanks a lot. You used the character class to match for / and text following that. And $ you are considering only the last pattern.
This is what i was looking for exactly. Thank you. I will also go through the earlier regex provided and understand how it works.

Comment: @MohanS: Yes, you are partially correct. Let me update my answer and add the explanation there itself.

Comment: Thankyou. One more question. Can we update this pattern to replace the last section following / only if it has content wrapped within { } . Not sure if this can be done. The below inputs should not be replaced.
Input 1 : /resource/{rID}/text/sometext
Input 2 : /resoruce/{objID}/text/[someId]

Comment: @MohanS: Updated my answer. Let me know for any queries further.